# Does anyone know an addin or macro to allow nesting files (dependentupon) from within VS?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

As per this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/f33c32df-14e4-4636-8c8e-c96f66666cb5/

"I can modify a C# project using notepad to make a file DependentUpon another file, but is there a way to do this in the IDE?"

All the links in the thread are dead. Anyone know something similar that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There an [Addin for that](http://blog.laurent.etiemble.com/index.php?post/2009/12/18/Add-Dependent-Files-Addin-for-Visual-Studio-2008) if you have Visual Studio 2008. It is the update of an [old project of mine](http://blog.laurent.etiemble.com/index.php?post/2006/12/08/101).

It can work on:

- File: it automatically add similar dependent files (A.Foo.cs is attached to A.cs)
- Project: all project's file are scanned for dependent files.
- Solution: all projects are scanned for dependent files.

Comment: awesome - any chance you can build a 2010 verison too (or even chuck it on codeplex)?

Comment: I will try to find some time to push the source somewhere.

Comment: any news on publishing the source? I'd like to add a feature - the ability to un-dependentupon the files. I've been finding that if I rename the parent, the children don't get renamed and there is no way in VS to rename them. I'd like to be able to unlink them, rename them and add them again.

Comment: I have upload a zip with the current sources, so you can start from it: http://blog.laurent.etiemble.com/public/AddDependentFiles_src.zip

Answer (score 6):

VSCommands - http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/

blah blah 30 characters blah